# How can I compile C source code using Emabarcadero C++?

Tags: c++, c, c++builder

I am wondering if it is possible for me to use Embarcadero c++ 2010 in order to compile a source code which i got from internet. I have this software installed in my PC, and i don't know to download a c compiler because i think it is already possible to do that using embarcadero.

I clicked on File -> New -> Other -> C Document

But the problem is when i typed my C code inside, i didn't get to click on the Compile button ( The green button ) because it is disabled. Can you help me compile a C source code using embarcadero c++ ?

Comment: If it won't let you just compile it, it might want you to create a new project and then add your source to that. I don't know Embarcadero but that's how VS would work.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the resulting .obj file? Do you want to add it to a C++ Builder project, or do you want to link it to a Delphi project with `$LINK`?

Answer (score 3):

- You need to create a .c file and add it to a project. Most likely New->Other->Console application.
- Pick C as source type.
- Don't click VCL.
- Click multithreading if your program is using it.
- Click "Console application" if your project is a text based console application of the usual `int main(void)` format. If it is a Windows API application with windows, don't click console application.
- You can specify project source if you already have a main() file, otherwise the IDE will create one for you.

Answer (score 2):

Given that this Embarcadero product looks like a full featured IDE, you probably need to start with a *project*, probably console based (depends on the code you downloaded).

Then you would add the C code to the project.

If you don't have a project, the IDE is not going to know how you want the results: library, DLL, console application, windowed application, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, C++ is a superset of C, meaning <s>all</s> most code that is valid in C is valid in C++. Just rename your `.c` files to `.cpp` and see if it works.

Note that some problems may persist with naming of variables (class, private, etc. Are valid variable names in C, but in C++ they will throw a compiler error), but for the most part this *should* work.

Comment: No. C++ is a *superset* of C, but not strict: in other words, *most* c is valid c++. Also, when you get into newer C standards, they get even farther apart.

Comment: @crashmstr true, but for most situations, these issues wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: True, but it really depends on the code he downloaded, and if he is having trouble with just getting it compiled, could he handle any differences or compiler errors if he did this?

Comment: The Embarcadero compiler will compile both C and C++ source code. If you rename the source file as suggested here then you interpret C code as C++ which could easily change the meaning of the code. The answer is not to compile as C++ but to compile as C.